# Would shooting an atom out the back of a rocket at the speed of light propel the rocket forward at the speed of light?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, speed-of-light, rocket-science, propulsion

Although impossible as far as we know, if we were to somehow shoot even an atom out the back of a rocket at the speed of light, would that propel the rocket forward at the speed of light?  If I understand Relativity correctly, my thought is that would require an infinite amount of energy.  Infinite action on the atom would cause an infinite reaction pushing the rocket forward at the speed of light.  Is this correct?

**Edit:**
Since that is an impossibility, what happens to the rocket's velocity as the atom's velocity approaches the speed of light.  Would the rocket approach the speed of light as well (as a limit in Calculus)?

Comment: *Although impossible as far as we know*  This is as far as you should have gone.  The rest was waste.  Nothing with mass can travel at the speed of light.

Comment: Maybe we should approach it as a limit in Calculus, the limit of the rocket's speed in relation to the particle's speed approaches the speed of light - would the rocket's speed approach the speed of light?

Comment: See [the relativistic rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_rocket) and [the photon rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_rocket).

Comment: Have you tried a back of the envelope calculation using relativistic momentum with a velocity close to but not equal to the speed of light? Velocities near the speed of light are of order $10^9$ while atomic mass is of order $10^{-27}$,  even with a large gamma factor the resulting momentum will be quite small

Comment: We cannot give meaningful answers to a physically impossible, as we now understand physics, question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for energy.

Accelerating atom to the speed of light means infinite energy. Spaceship just collapsed into a black hole.

Accelerating atom to a large percent of the speed of light means energy came from somewhere. Lets assume energy was stored in the same atom. Then as you increase the speed, you need more and more energy to be wasted on accelerating this atom. And that means less and less mass will be available to actually be ejected.

Closest thing there is to what you are asking is an anti-matter drive. All of the mass gets converted to light. Using it you can achieve about half of the speed of light if half of the mass of a spaceship is this matter with anti-matter fuel. There is no more dense energy storage that we know of. And if energy is provided from outside, then just use it to flash light behind and get infinite acceleration time, and get arbitrarily close to the speed of light.

TLDR: count not just mass, but also energy, because energy also requires mass.

Answer (score 2):

The atom will not travel at the speed of light. Period. IF it travels at the speed of light, the laws of physics have been violated, in which case, why would you expect other laws to hold?

So no, it cannot.